# Explode from a txt file

Tags: arrays, indexing, explode

I use explode in my php code to load the strings from a txt file into an array. The strings are loaded into array with no problem, however, the first element has an index 0 but I want it to have an index 1. How do I achieve that?

I appreciate any help cause I've tried so many things and nothing seems to be working and I feel I got stuck.

Comment: Can you share some code here, question without code is hard to understand

Comment: arrays start at index `0` in most languages. And there is no way to change that. If you want your "real" data to start at index 1 you can use [`array_unshift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to insert a dummy element after loading your array from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_unshift` to insert dummy element then remove it using `unset` as follows :

```
$ex_array = array("PHP","JAVA","C#","Python", "Javascript", "C");

array_unshift($ex_array,"");

unset($ex_array[0]);
```

Comment: This is perfect! It works the way I need it to. Thank you so much, I appreciate it! Best!

Comment: Glad to hear, enjoy coding

Comment: Can you accept my answer if you see it useful, thanks

Comment: No problem, just tell me how do i accept your answer? Sorry but im fairly new in here and no idea what should i do.

Comment: Have a look into this question/answer to understand how to make it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow